# VertialScrollLayout in Android

Tags: android

I was trying to use Scroll Layout in Android. I want my views to get scrolled vertically. But I could see only HorizontalScrollLayout. What do I do If I want Vertical?

Here is the Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/lion"
            android:background="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="20dp"

            android:id="@+id/image1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/lion"
            android:background="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="20dp"

            android:id="@+id/image2" />

    </LinearLayout>



</HorizontalScrollView>

Can anyone suggest me the solution?
```

Comment: You want the regular [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: Any solution you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use ScrollView. Here is the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), and here is [sample](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Please look at into [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) for reference.

Sample code for Vertical ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    // Here all child view like TextView, Button, ImageView, Layouts

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```